# XPages visible formula does not work

Tags: xpages, visibility

I would liek to use the same hide formula in XPages button. 
All Fields below is dateTime Field...
Orjinal lotusScript formula is :

```
OnayG="" | Onaylandi!="" | OnayTalep!=""
```

[image: Hide Action If Formula is True Formula Screen]

```
if (document1.isEditable())
{
    var OnayG = document1.getItemValueDate("OnayG").toString();
    var Onaylandi = document1.getItemValueDate("Onaylandi").toString();
    var OnayTalep = document1.getItemValueDate("OnayTalep").toString();

    if (OnayG =="" || Onaylandi!="" | OnayTalep!="")
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used a single "|" before OnayTalep variable in the if statement. This is the correct code:

```
if (document1.isEditable())
{
    var OnayG = document1.getItemValueDate("OnayG").toString();
    var Onaylandi = document1.getItemValueDate("Onaylandi").toString();
    var OnayTalep = document1.getItemValueDate("OnayTalep").toString();

    if (OnayG =="" || Onaylandi!="" || OnayTalep!="")
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

your logic regarding isEditable is not the same.
your classic notes version says
"if not editable - hide"
but your xpages logic says:
"if not editable - visible"

the confusion may come from the fact that in notes, a tick or a 'true' value is used to **hide** something, but in xpages, a true value means it is rendered or **visible**